# How to use npx tslint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

How to use npx tslint?

1. `npx tslint -c ./tsconfig.json "src/**/*.ts?(x)"`

```
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/service/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint src/blah.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration
```

**NOPE**

2. `npx tslint ./src/components`

```
'./src/components' does not exist. This will be an error in TSLint 6.
```

Actually, the `./src/components` dir does exist. But, OK. **Nope**

How is it actually possible to use this tool?

Comment: Surely you read the instructions? https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

Comment: Note that TSLint is deprecated. You should look into using TypeScript-ESLint instead, especially if this is a new project that doesn't have linting already set up.